# E: Package 'python3-distutils' has no installation candidate

Tags: tensorflow, putty, modulenotfounderror

I am currently using the Google core dev board and using Putty to enter the code.
While performing the code, I got the error as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/generate_detections.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

So I typed `sudo pip install tensorflow`.

but I got another error as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mendel/.local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir, enum
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version, site_packages, user_site
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

So I typed `sudo apt install python3-distutils`.

but I got another error as below.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-distutils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libpython3.7-stdlib

E: Package 'python3-distutils' has no installation candidate
```

I can no longer find a solution.
Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Can you install dist-utils again with the below command  and let us know.                 sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt install python3-distutils

Just install in your Ubuntu terminal after you can install other packages!